# How to ignore file types from being archived in my shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, aix

I have a shell script that runs on AIX 7.1 and the purpose of it is to archive a bunch of different directories using CPIO.

We pass in the directories to be archived to CPIO from a flat file called synclive_cpio.list.

Here is a snippet of the script..

```
#!/bin/ksh
CPIO_LIST="$BASE/synclive_cpio.list"
DUMP_DIR=/usr4/sync_stage
LOG_FILE=/tmp/synclive.log

run_cpio()
{
while LINE=: read -r f1 f2
do
  sleep 1
  cd $f1
  echo "Sending CPIO processing for $f1 to background." >> $LOG_FILE
  time find . -print | cpio -o | gzip > $DUMP_DIR/$f2.cpio.gz &
done <"$CPIO_LIST"
wait
}
```

Here is what we have in the synclive.cpio.list file...

```
/usr2/devel_config usr2_devel_config
/usr/local usr_local
/usr1/config usr1_config
/usr1/releases usr1_releases
```

When the CPIO is running, it will archive everything in the passed directory.. what I would like to do is try to exclude a few file extension types such as *.log and *.tmp as we don't need to archive those.

Any idea how to change run_cpio() block to support this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude them in the `find` command

```
time find . ! \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*.tmp' \) -print | cpio -o | gzip > $DUMP_DIR/$f2.cpio.gz &
```

You can keep adding `-o *.suffix` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use egrep -v in the pipeline.  I believe that would be a teeny tiny bit more efficient.

```
time find . -print | egrep -v '\.(tmp|log)$' | cpio -o | gz
```

To me, it is also easier to read and modify if the list gets really long.